# In app purchase unfinished transaction in a particular device

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, in-app-purchase

Im doing a in app purchase non consumable,the issue is when I start the app there comes a alert view filled with a mail address already and asking password.This particular issue happens only in the same device which I test where else it never happened when I tested in other device. 
Somewhere I have to place this `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];` to get that unfinished transaction done but I'm completely confused because I've placed in necessary places .This is my existing code

```
-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {
        switch (transaction.transactionState) {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:

                [self UnlockPurchase];
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                NSLog(@"Restored ");
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
               break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:NSLog(@"Transaction Failed");

                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
            default:
                break;          
       }
    } 

- (IBAction)Restore:(id)sender {

    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];

}

-(void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue {
    [self UnlockPurchase];
}

- (IBAction)BuyProduct:(id)sender {

    SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:_product];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
}
```

Similar problem I had previously on another device just because I left out `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction]`in `SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored`then my problem was solved.When I used this test user to restore the purchase,it restores without entering into `SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored` case.When I try to purchase again it says **you've already purchased item but hasn't been downloaded**.Now I need is to get rid of that login containing a email address filled already pops up when I start? HELP !

Comment: are you correctly implementing all the code that goes in the application delegate? can you show your appdelegate.m code related to in app purchases?

Comment: I have't placed any thing in appdelegate.m / I use just two view controllers view controller and purchased view controller(the above code). @Chiquis

Comment: This is the action I used in my vc after purchase it has enable the content in the same vc "-(IBAction)PurchaseItem:(id)sender {
    
    _purchaseController = [[PurchasedViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    _purchaseController.productID = @"XXX";
 [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:_purchaseController];
    [self presentViewController:_purchaseController animated:YES completion:NULL];
    [_purchaseController getProductID:self];
    
}"

Comment: That is the problem, you have to set code in your app delegate. check my answer

Answer (score -1):

You are missing the methods that handle the response of the app store to your application. They should be in your app delegate:

Follow apples documentation for delivering products:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/DeliverProduct.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH5-SW3

Alternatively you can use ray wenderlichs tutorial:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/

Take notice that these methods are the ones that should control the content delivery, for the purchase being successful or not.

Comment: [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:observer]; this code I've placed in my vc action(code in comments) and also I've used this "-(void)Purchased {
    Label.text = @"item has been purchased";
    _gonext.enabled=YES;
    NSUserDefaults *saveapp = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [saveapp setBool:TRUE forKey:k_Save];
    [saveapp synchronize];
}" in the same vc and checked condition in viewdidload. Is this wrong ? ! This error occurs when I use this specific test user acc but I have another acc that just works perfectly purchases and restore with on issue.

Comment: What i think is happening is that, the test user with the problem didnt finish the transaction (it was cut in the middle) which is why its still pending. there are 2 things here, to stop receiving the notification you should finalize it (with the code you already placed) . The second thing is that apple will notify the DEVICE as soon as the app is launched, (not apple per se but the register in the device). This is why the methods should be in the app delegate. Anyways, the best practice is to actually have them in the app delegate.

Comment: Definitely I'll place it on app delegate.What actually happens is first I logout from settings>iTunesacc then run my app it pops up the alert view of my(problematic) test user mail acc filled in.When I enter my password it asks another time finally I gets off.After when I try to make purchase it fails with a message as I mentioned in my question and restore button it restores without calling "SKPaymentRestored".When I stop Xcode & logout the acc from device settings then run back again it starts to show that alert view instead when I stay in that acc in device settings there is no problem.

Comment: @Chiquis what methods should be in the app-delegate? is the device going to call them even without `addTransactionObserver`?

Comment: No, you need to add an observer to process the methods. You can check which methods are called by looking at the protocol: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentTransactionObserver_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/SKPaymentTransactionObserver/paymentQueue:updatedTransactions: